# Android App crashes if you close a comment whilst refreshing answers

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

I ran into an obscure crash bug today: I decided to dismiss one of my comments during a particularly long refresh. It turns out that reliably crashes the app.

Here's the full reproduction steps:

1. Find an answer.
2. Hit 'Add comment' to leave a comment on that answer.
3. Refresh the answers - you'll still have your comment entry box active.
4. Whilst the answers are refreshing, hit the `[v]` icon to dismiss the comment entry.
5. The app crashes.

That's it. Questions seem to be fine - it's just the answers crashing.

[image]

(The black area is where my keyboard was - the app didn't resize to fill that area. It seems that once I dismissed the comment, it at least managed to close the keyboard before crashing.)

Comment: In addition of the Q&A page renewal since v1.0.50, I couldn't repro this from step 3 on v1.0.82 (beta): while posting a comment, the app will show a progress dialog, preventing any interaction with the app (e.g. tapping the "hide comment box" icon doesn't do anything). After that, the comment box will be automatically closed.

Comment: Yep, this seems fine now.